# LaTeX Extension doesn't work on VS Code and keeps giving ENOENT error

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This is what my *Terminal* shows for $PATH

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Users/sathvik/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/sathvik/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory
```

I have deleted all possible files linked to LaTeX which I got from MacTeX and I have installed MiKTeX. The following is the path for MiKTeX

```
/Applications/MiKTeX Console.app/Contents/bin
```

I want to use LaTeX in VS Code and I only have the [Latex Workshop Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop)and [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) Enabled (reload is done).The following is my JSON Settings.

```
{
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"notebook.lineNumbers": "on",

"code-runner.executorMap": {
"javascript": "node",
"java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"php": "php",
"python": "python",
"perl": "perl",
"perl6": "perl6",
"ruby": "ruby",
"go": "go run",
"lua": "lua",
"groovy": "groovy",
"powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
"bat": "cmd /c",
"shellscript": "bash",
"fsharp": "fsi",
"csharp": "scriptcs",
"vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
"typescript": "ts-node",
"coffeescript": "coffee",
"scala": "scala",
"swift": "swift",
"julia": "julia",
"crystal": "crystal",
"ocaml": "ocaml",
"r": "Rscript",
"applescript": "osascript",
"clojure": "lein exec",
"haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
"rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"racket": "racket",
"scheme": "csi -script",
"ahk": "autohotkey",
"autoit": "autoit3",
"dart": "dart",
"pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"haskell": "runhaskell",
"nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
"lisp": "sbcl --script",
"kit": "kitc --run",
"v": "v run",
"sass": "sass --style expanded",
"scss": "scss --style expanded",
"less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
"FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
"latex": "latex"

},
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
      "name": "latexmk ",
      "tools": [
        "latexmk"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex`×2",
      "tools": [
        "pdflatex",
        "bibtex",
        "pdflatex",
        "pdflatex"
      ]
    }
  ],

  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
      "name": "latexmk",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "-pdf",
        "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
        "%DOC%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "pdflatex",
      "command": "pdflatex",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOC%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "bibtex",
      "command": "bibtex",
      "args": [
        "%DOCFILE%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    }
  ],

"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
"jupyter.jupyterServerType": "local",
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
"notebook.consolidatedRunButton": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,


"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    "language-julia.interrupt"
],
"julia.symbolCacheDownload": true,
"julia.executablePath": "/Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia ",


"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"snyk.features.openSourceSecurity": false,
"snyk.features.codeSecurity": false,
"julia.enableTelemetry": true,
"python.diagnostics.sourceMapsEnabled": true,
"python.disableInstallationCheck": true,
"bracketPairColorizer.depreciation-notice": false,
"extension.runMatlab": "/Applications/MATLAB_R2021b.app/Contents/MacOS/MATLAB",
"arduino.path": "/Users/sathvik/Desktop/Arduino.app",
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true
}
}
```

I've exhausted every possible resource but no matter what I do, every time I try to build my LaTeX project, I keep getting the following error:

```
[20:16:24] The document of the active editor: file:///Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX            Files/Hertz's Experiment_1.tex
    [20:16:24] The languageId of the document: latex
    [20:16:24] Current workspace folders: ["file:///Users/sathvik/Desktop"]
    [20:16:24] Current workspaceRootDir: file:///Users/sathvik/Desktop
    [20:16:24] Found root file from active editor: /Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files/Hertz's Experiment_1.tex
    [20:16:24] Keep using the same root file: /Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files/Hertz's Experiment_1.tex
    [20:16:24] Building root file: /Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files/Hertz's Experiment_1.tex
    [20:16:24] Build root file /Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files/Hertz's Experiment_1.tex
    [20:16:24] outDir: /Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files
    [20:16:24] Recipe step 1: latexmk, -synctex=1,-interaction=nonstopmode,-file-line-error,-pdf,-outdir=/Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files,/Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX  Files/Hertz's Experiment_1
    [20:16:24] Recipe step env: {}
    [20:16:24] cwd: /Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files
    [20:16:24] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: undefined.
    [20:16:24] LaTeX fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT, . PID: undefined.
    [20:16:24] Does the executable exist? $PATH:   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
    [20:16:24] Does the executable exist? $Path: undefined
    [20:16:24] The environment variable $SHELL: /bin/zsh
    [20:16:26] Manager.fileWatcher.getWatched: {"/Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files":      ["Hertz's Experiment_1.tex"]}
    [20:16:26] Manager.filesWatched: ["/Users/sathvik/Desktop/TeX Files/Hertz's Experiment_1.tex"]
[20:16:26] BibWatcher.bibWatcher.getWatched: {}
[20:16:26] BibWatcher.bibsWatched: []
[20:16:26] PdfWatcher.pdfWatcher.getWatched: {}  
[20:16:26] PdfWatcher.pdfsWatched: []'
```

And

```
Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.
```

If any more information is required, please request so.
I'm honestly exhausted from this and would really appreciate it if anyone would help me with this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't use miktex on a mac. Texlive (and by extension mactex) is better maintained, more stable and has much more users who will report bugs before you stumble upon them.